# How to add Done button on numberpad keyboard for VPMOTPView in swift

Tags: ios, swift, view, keyboard

I am using VPMOTPView for OTP fields, when i tap on the OTP view here i am getting keyboard with numberpad but here how to add Done Button to keyboard.

[image]

**I am able to add Done button on keyboard for textfield, but how to add for VPMOTPView.**

```
class OTPViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var otpView: VPMOTPView!
var phone : String?
var otp   : String?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //self.navigationBarButton()
    otpView.otpFieldsCount = 6
    otpView.otpFieldDefaultBorderColor = UIColor.lightGray
    otpView.otpFieldEnteredBorderColor = UIColor(named: "LightPrimaryColor") ?? UIColor.blue
    otpView.otpFieldErrorBorderColor = UIColor.red
    otpView.otpFieldBorderWidth = 1
    otpView.delegate = self
    otpView.shouldAllowIntermediateEditing = false
    otpView.otpFieldSize = 25
    otpView.otpFieldDisplayType = .underlinedBottom
    otpView.otpFieldEntrySecureType=false
    otpView.initializeUI()
    emailIconLabel.text = "We have sent an sms with OTP \nto \(phone!)"
    self.getOTPService()
}
}
```

Please help me with the code for adding Done on keyboard.

Comment: add third party library pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift' and the done button will appear.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: happy to help you cheers man

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First introduce this `extension` on `UITextField` to add `Done` button.

```
extension UITextField {

    /// Adding a done button on the keyboard
    func addDoneButtonOnKeyboard() {
        let doneToolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 50))
        doneToolbar.barStyle = .default

        let flexSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        let done = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(self.doneButtonAction))

        let items = [flexSpace, done]
        doneToolbar.items = items
        doneToolbar.sizeToFit()

        self.inputAccessoryView = doneToolbar
    }

    /// Done button callback
    @objc func doneButtonAction() {
        self.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

Now, call the `addDoneButtonOnKeyboard` method on all the `UITextField` instances used in the `VPMOTPView` as below,

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //self.navigationBarButton()
    otpView.otpFieldsCount = 6
    otpView.otpFieldDefaultBorderColor = UIColor.lightGray
    otpView.otpFieldEnteredBorderColor = UIColor(named: "LightPrimaryColor") ?? UIColor.blue
    otpView.otpFieldErrorBorderColor = UIColor.red
    otpView.otpFieldBorderWidth = 1
    otpView.delegate = self
    otpView.shouldAllowIntermediateEditing = false
    otpView.otpFieldSize = 25
    otpView.otpFieldDisplayType = .underlinedBottom
    otpView.otpFieldEntrySecureType=false
    otpView.initializeUI()
    emailIconLabel.text = "We have sent an sms with OTP \nto \(phone!)"

    otpView.subviews.compactMap({ $0 as? VPMOTPTextField}).forEach { tv in
        tv.addDoneButtonOnKeyboard()
    }
    self.getOTPService()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can append a toolbar at top of the keyboard with a done button.

```
extension UITextField {

func addDoneButtonOnKeyboard() {
    let doneToolbar: UIToolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 50))
    doneToolbar.barStyle = .default
    let flexSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    let done = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(someMethod))
    let items = [flexSpace, done]
    doneToolbar.items = items
    doneToolbar.sizeToFit()
    inputAccessoryView = doneToolbar
}
}
```

The imported part is `inputAccessoryView` on your UITextField.